# Model/Association Design For New Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, database-design

I'm about to start building an application in Rails (just started learning Rails, so figured this would be a good, basic exercise) and wanted to solicit some feedback on how to architect my models and associations.  The application is designed to host a "game" in which users guess what songs they think will be played at a given concert each show the band plays.  So far, I have the following models (with approximate attributes):

- `User`: keep track of active users (`user_name`, `user_password`, `user_email`, etc.)
- `Submission`: keep track of a given user's guess for a given show (`date_of_show`, `guess_1`, `guess_2`, `guess_3`, `user_id`)
- `Show`: keep track of each show the band plays (`date_of_show`, `songs_played`)
- `Song`: keep track of band's current catalog (`song_name`)

The relationship between `User` and `Submission` is pretty straightforward:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :submissions
end

class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

When it comes to the relationships between the other pieces though, things become a bit more unclear, so I have the following questions:

- Each `Submission` corresponds to one `Show`.  Does it make sense to say that each `Submission` `belongs_to` a `Show` and each `Show` `has_many` `Submissions` using `date_of_show` as the key?
- Is it necessary to have a `Song` model at all?  In the initial version of the application, it will simply be used as a list to validate guesses (i.e.; populate a `select` drop down).
- If I should keep the `Song` model, how do I associate that with the other models?  A `User` doesn't have a song, so that one's easy, but each `Submission` has three `Songs` and each `Show` can have a varying number of `Songs`.
- On the point of each `Show` having a varying number of `Songs`, is the best way to approach this to store them in an array, ala this post (http://amberonrails.com/storing-arrays-in-a-database-field-w-rails-activerecord/) or is there a better way?  Ultimately, I will need to implement some method that loops through each `Submission`, check `guess_1`, `guess_2`, and `guess_3` against the `songs_played` array (or whatever other alternative I use) in the `Show` model, and produce a score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first steps, design your application like the real life. When you have more experience, you can drop some models, simulate others for some optimization.

In real life, how to design a show ? It's a band playing songs. How to design a band ? It's a set of people (not used here) having songs. How to design a submission ? It's a user thinking a song is played at a time.

Then, you can have theses models :

```
User (name...)
Song (name, band_id) : belongs_to a band and have many show_songs
Band (name) : has_many songs and has_many shows
Show (band_id) : belongs_to band
ShowSong (show_id, song_id, datetime) : belongs_to show and song
Submission (user_id, song_id, show_song_id) : belongs_to song and show_song
```

It's not a unique solution, you can design what you want.

I design theses models from some Rails practices:

- Don't use date_of_show as a key, use an _id (that's why I insert show_song)
- It's *necessary* to have a model when model have specific methods or must be registered in database
- don't use guess_1, guess_2, ... Use an have_many guesses

Comment: I'm having a hard time envisioning how some of these tables link to one another.  Could you please elaborate on the ties between `Song`, `Show`, `ShowSong`, and `Submission` a bit more please?

Comment: The link between theses classes are denoted in my description. Consider that when you have `X has_many Y`, then you must have `Y belongs_to X`. And If you have `Y belongs_to X`, standard Rails implies you have a `x_id` in the attributes of `Y`.

Comment: I just read my description and correct an issue on the `Song` description. If you want more details, the `ShowSong` represents a class simulating an `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation (check some documentation about it).

Comment: It's starting to become a bit more clear, but I'm still having trouble visualizing how all of the tables link to one another.  Would it be possible for you to provide a rough schema diagram?

Comment: To clarify on my question, how exactly does Rails handle the `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationships?  If I create a new `Show` then how exactly do I link up the `Songs`?  If a `Show` contains the `Shows` with `show_id` 1, 2, 4, and 5, how is that linked?  Does Rails automatically create a table that contains every `show_id` and `song_id` combination that is used for querying?

Comment: @AvocadoRivalry An `X has_and_belongs_to_many Y` relation creates a table with `x_id` and `y_id`, but don't generates any model. Sometimes, you have to replace this `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation by a model `Z`, where `Z belongs_to X` and `Z belongs_to Y`. The table is the same (with an `id` attribute and with an other name), but you can add new attributes to it and add specific methods. For your schema diagram, it's super simple, just read the `belongs_to` (1--n) and the `have_many` (n--1) relations.

Comment: Thanks @ForgetTheNorm - I went ahead and used a `has_many...through` which worked wonderfully.  Thanks for helping me through this!